# Can't get Intel HD 5500 graphics to work with Debian

Tags: debian, graphics, intel-graphics, zenbook

I'm using Debian 8, but my integrated graphics card does not seem to be used.

This is on an Asus Zenbook UX303 which uses HD 5500 integrated graphics:

```
$ sudo lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:183d]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 64
    Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

It seems to say there is a driver in use, however, it doesn't seem the machine is actually using that graphics card:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

**How do I get debian to actually use the integrated graphics card?**

```
$ uname -a
Linux zenbook 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've also tried the 4.0.2 kernel from unstable, which doesn't change anything; uname:

```
$ uname -a
Linux zenbook 4.0.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.2-1 (2015-05-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unfortunately Jessie as released doesn't fully support Broadwell graphics. The required drivers have been backported though, so if you [enable Jessie backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) you can fix this.

First you need to add Jessie backports to your repositories, if it's not already there (thanks to [Anders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4367/anders) for the reminder to use a separate file):

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as `root`), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

should allow X to use your HD 5500 properly.

Enabling backports is safe: newer packages are not picked up automatically from backports, you need to explicitly select them using `-t jessie-backports` as above.