# Intel HD 405 Graphics isn't working in Debian

Tags: debian, intel-graphics

I'm using Debian Jessie on an asrock j3710 Mainboard and the graphics is suprisingly slow.

I stumbled across [This Thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207855/cant-get-intel-hd-5500-graphics-to-work-with-debian) and installed `xserver-xorg-video-intel` from `jessie-backports` accordingly.

But it seems that still the graphics card isn't in use.

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b1] (rev 35) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:22b1]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

and

```
$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

How can I get Debian to use the graphics card?

Output of dmesg:

```
dmesg | grep i915
[    6.198455] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    6.198470] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20160229 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    7.305103] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device


$ dmesg | grep drm
[    5.620931] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    5.650541] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    5.650550] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    5.653228] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2    (21.10.2013).
[    5.653231] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    6.198470] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20160229 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.203243] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    7.305103] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
```

ldd $(which glxinfo)    produces:

```
ldd $(which glxinfo)                                                                                             
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0139a000)                                                                                         
libGLEW.so.1.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.1.10 (0x00007f674810d000)                                            
libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007f6747e9f000)                                                    
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f6747c2d000)                                                      
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6747928000)                                                            
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f67475e5000)                                                    
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f67473d2000)                                                  
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6747031000)                                                            
libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007f6746e18000)                                                    
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f6746c07000)                                                      
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f67468fc000)                                              
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f67466e6000)                                                    
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f67464bc000)                                                    
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f67462b9000)                                          
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f67460b6000)                                    
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f6745eae000)                                          
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f6745cac000)
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f6745a7e000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f674587a000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f6745674000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f6745472000)
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f6745258000)
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f6745053000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6744e31000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f6744c2a000)
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f6744a1b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f67447fe000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f67445f9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cfc8576000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f6744390000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f674418b000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6743f86000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f6743d7e000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f6743b60000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f674395b000)
```

Comment: What does `ldd $(which glxinfo)` produce?

Comment: I added the output to the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably also need an updated kernel from the backports:

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

You *might* also need updated firmware (from non-free backports):

```
sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

Comment: Hello @stephen-kitt,
thanks for sharing. I tried your advice but stil get the same output and graphics is slow.
Do I need to enable the driver somehow?

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but did you reboot? Are there any messages relating to `i915` or `drm` in `dmesg`'s output?

Comment: I edited the question and attached the dmesg output. I'm not sure how to interpret it.