# More than one driver

Tags: debian, gnome3, intel-graphics, opengl, mesa

I am using Debian 8.6 32 bit on Dell Inspiron 3558 with Gnome desktop.

When I log in using GNOME or GNOME Classic,

```
root@localhost:/home/santosh# glxinfo  
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

When I log in using GNOME Wayland

```
root@localhost:/home/santosh# glxinfo 
name of display: :1
display: :1  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 [8086:1616] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b0]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I need you to see different drivers are used at the same time.

Have a look at the OpenGL renderer string

I want to use Intel's drivers not VMWares's

VMWares' driver is not working for me. It doesn't give any visual effects.
Plays videos slowly.

**SOLUTION**: [Can't get Intel HD 5500 graphics to work with Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207855/cant-get-intel-hd-5500-graphics-to-work-with-debian)

Comment: Please consider posting text instead of images if you can.

Comment: Instead of adding information in the comments, please edit the question.  Comments may not be read by everyone and are terrible for trying to format things in

Comment: Please edit by adding the   output of `lspci | grep -i  'vga'`

Comment: I have replaced images with text.